# looping over the lines of a file spliiting each line in columns and creating an array of each column

Tags: perl

Sorry if my question is too obvious, I´m new in perl.

My code is the following:

```
open (FILE1, "$ARG[0]") or die

@lines1;

$i=1;

while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    push (@lines1, $_);
    my @{columns$1}= split (/\s+/, $lines1[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

It gives an error saying

```
Can´t declare array dereference at the line my @{columns$1}= split (/\s+/, $lines1[$i]);
```

I wanted to create columns1, columns2, columns3... and each one of them would have the columns of the corresponding line (columns1 of the line 1, columns2 of line 2 and so on...)

Because before I tried to do it this way (below) and every time it was splitting the lines but it was overwriting the @columns1 array so only the last line was saved, at the end I had the values of the 10th line (because it starting counting at 0)

```
for my $i (0..9) {
    @columns1 = split (/\s+/, $lines1[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Learn basic concepts first, http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-ARRAYS

Answer (score 1):

To split a table file in its columns, you could do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#ALWAYS put 'use warnings' and 'use strict' on the beginning of your code. It makes
#your life easier when debugging your code, and save you from having empty variables
#making weird things all over your code, and many other things. 
#It is a good practice for "safe Perl coding".
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($file) = @ARGV;

open(my $in, "<$ARGV[0]"); #In your code you used an old filehandle format, FILE1.
                           #You should use the new format - $file1 as it allows you 
                           #to use any scalar variable as a filehandle.
my @column1;  
while(<$in>) {
    chomp;

    #Here comes the splitting:
    my @table = split(/\s+/);

    #if you want to print the first column:
    print "$table[0]\n"; #remember that Perl starts to count from 0;

   #if you know which columns you want to work with:
   push(@column1, $table[0]);
}
```

Even though I am an adept of the **do-first-and-learn-to-code-by-fixing-your-mistakes** approach to learn to code, you should really **take some time to work through the basics of Perl**, as **@mpapec** said. Learn the basics will save a lot of time and effort when dealing with problems like yours.